# SDL 2.0 enlarge texture

Tags: c++, c, sdl

In order to make buttons, I create and render texture that way:

```
typedef struct{
    SDL_Rect pos;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    int hovered;
} button;

button getButton(int x, int y, char * label, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color color){
    button btn;
    btn.hovered = false;
    btn.pos.x = x;
    btn.pos.y = y;
    SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, label, color);
    btn.pos.w = surface->w;
    btn.pos.h = surface->h;
    btn.texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return btn;
}

void drawButton(button btn){
    SDL_RenderCopyEx( renderer, btn.texture, NULL, &btn.pos, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    if(btn.hovered){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0x00);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &btn.pos);
}
```

The problem is that I get texture which size equals one of label. How can I increase texture pixel size without stretching it i.e. add blank spaces to the side of it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which version of SDL? And where is the code that renders the button?

Comment: @E_net4 edited question to represent both rendering and ver. of SDL. Didn't really tried anything because can't come up with any idea

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
void drawButton(button btn){
    SDL_RenderCopyEx( renderer, btn.texture, NULL, &btn.pos, 0, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    if(btn.hovered){
        int padding = 10;
        SDL_Rect pos = {btn.pos.x - padding,   btn.pos.y - padding, 
                        btn.pos.w + 2*padding, btn.pos.h + 2*padding };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0x00);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &pos);
    }
}
```

That way only the size of the rectangle changes, obviously I just pulled 10 for the size of padding out of thin air, you'll want to pick something appropriate yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I was thinking about similar way, but this would cause certain troubles with handling mouse movements so I would have to add another SDL_Rect field to my struct which seems wrong to me

Comment: @osamurai Two things, I just fixed a bug in the code I posted, and two, no the `SDL_Rect` in the button struct is not altered so this will always render in the same place. The bug was I forgot to change the `SDL_RenderDrawRect()` to use the temporary `SDL_Rect`

Comment: somewhere else(in mouse handling function) lies code like this: 
`if((x >= btn.pos.x && x <= btn.pos.x + btn.pos.w) &&...)) btn.hovered = true;` which means i'll have to duplicate this temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it. To enlarge the texture you create surface representing background of button, then combine them:

```
button getButton(int x, int y, char * label, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color color){
    button btn;
    btn.hovered = false;
    btn.pos.x = x;
    btn.pos.y = y;

    SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, label, color);
    SDL_Surface* back = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, surface->w+10, surface->h+10,
                                            32, 0, 0, 0, 0);// create a black background
    SDL_Rect t = {5, 5, back->w, back->w}; // place in a background to place label
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, back, &t); // combining surfaces
    btn.pos.w = back->w;
    btn.pos.h = back->h;

    btn.texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, back);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return btn;
}
```